# How to show certificate selection popup to the user in WKWebview embedded browser in mac

Tags: macos, authentication, wkwebview, keychain, client-certificates

I'm trying to add support for client certificate based authentication (cba) in an embedded browser of my app in Mac. Here is the code I have.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler 
{
NSString *lAuthenticationMethod = [[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod];
.....
else if ([lAuthenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
    lCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:lCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, lCredential);
}
else if ([lAuthenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate]) {
// **Q1. How to let the user manually select the Identity from the keychain using a popup?**(like in below screenshot)
}
.....
// Code to retrieve certificate from Identity, then get credential and pass it to CompletionHandler goes here
}
```

[Certificate selection popup screenshot - similar to Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woqaz.png)

**Q1. How to let the user manually select the Identity from the keychain using a popup?(like in above screenshot)**

Also if someone can point me to an example code of manual certificate selection popup in MacOS in Objective C for client certificate based authentication in WKWebkit, it would be helpful!